# adding cell values to active cell

Tags: excel, addition

I would like to create a macro that adds the value on the cell immediately below (eg B2)  the active cell (eg B1), to the value on the active cell itself and then clears cell B2. Thus B1 would be equal to B1+B2 (if B1=23 and B2=2 then B1 will have the value 25. How to go about it?

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njPJN.jpg)

Comment: I assume this is for Excel? You should add relevant tags to your question so people know which software you're working with.

Comment: Are you looking to see that value in B3?  Is it an automatic process when a cell loses focus, or triggered by pressing a button?

Comment: please see image enclosed

Comment: will the active cell change or always be B1?

Comment: Do the values in cell A2 and A3 have to match?  What if there were two cells as "book"? do those also need to be added/cleared?

Comment: cells do not have to match, I will choose the active cell and then run the macro

Comment: the active cell will remain B1 but the value will change from 23 to 25

Comment: Solved:
Sub ----
 Dim rng As Range ----    
     Set rng = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))    -----
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng) -----
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Clear ----
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Offset function to look for a cell relative to the active cell:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value + ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value
ActiveCell.Offset(1).ClearContents
```

In this case, we're looking 1 row below the active cell, but you could do the following if you needed above

```
ActiveCell.Offset(-1)
```